# Need help to create an sqlite database at a particular folder

Tags: java, sqlite

I have created an app which consists of the sqlite database. I have created an exe of that code. I need to create the database at a particular folder for example at c:\Windows, so that the end user can't aware of the database. I have created the database, and it get extracted at the executing folder itself. Any suggestion...

Comment: little remark: you will need admin rights to write to c:\windows, so UAC will be activated => user notices.

Comment: If I wish to create the db at c drive itself is it possible.. how to achieve it, any examples

Answer (score 2):

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
```

Somewhere in your code you will find lines resembling the two above. Edit the connection string `"jdbc:sqlite:test.db"` to the path you want the database to be, i.e. :

```
"jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Windows\\yourdb.db"
```

**Note:** For folders like `C:\Windows`, you will need administrator privileges on Win Vista/7.

Comment: Thanks cularis. Then how to get the administrator privileges through code. Or is there any other way to hide the database.

Comment: You can't get admin privileges without the user giving them to you. What do you mean with hide the database? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I rely on the database to run the exe for a particular number of times. If the end user can able to view, edit or delete the database he can run the exe as much as he can.

Comment: Ok, you can't do that. The user can easily find out where it is by looking at the open file handlers. You could implement a solution that checks with a web service.

Comment: Could you please be more specific with implementing a solution that checks with a web service.